# How to update GeoWebCache defaults after change gwc-gs.xml without restart GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, geoserver-rest-api

I have an app, which need to change GWC defaults by changing gwc-gs.xml, but i cant do it without restarting GeoServer. I tried use API gwc/rest/reload and geoserver/rest/reload and geoserver/rest/reset and combinations thereof, but it didn't work. Are there any options to change the GWC defaults by API without restarting GeoServer?

Comment: Do you mean that restart does work?

Comment: yes, after rebooting the entire geoserver (systemctl or docker restart) the settings are installed